# Mixed model with one between and two within variables partially crossed. How to include items in random effects?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

We have an experiment where participants solve two items presented in one of two types of brochure (OLD vs NEW).

Participants see the first item with a randomly assigned age (20 vs 40) and a randomly assigned medical condition (Down syndrome vs Breast cancer). For the second item, they see the remaining age and medical condition combination. So, if the first item is NEW brochure, 40 yo, Breast cancer, the second is NEW brochure, 20 yo, Down syndrome.

Below you can see the first 6 rows of the DF.

```
   ID    brochure_between medicalcondition_within age_within PPV_error PPV_accuracy item_order
   <fct> <fct>            <fct>                   <fct>          <dbl>        <dbl>      <int>
 1 1     OLD              Breast cancer           40              8.82            0          1
 2 1     OLD              Down syndrome           20             79.6             0          2
 3 2     NEW              Breast cancer           40              4.96            1          1
 4 2     NEW              Down syndrome           20             70               0          2
 5 3     OLD              Down syndrome           20             -7.19            0          1
 6 3     OLD              Breast cancer           40              8.74            0          2
```

The Dependent variable can be either a continuous one, PPV_error (from -90 to +90), or a categorical one, PPV_accuracy (0 or 1).

So, we have one between variable (brochure) and two within variables (age, medical condition), but the participants only see two of the four possible combinations of the within variables. In fact, age is the "interesting" within variable, as it affects what people need to calculate, and medical condition is just a way to show two items avoiding repeating the context.

What would be the best way to analyze the data? Our first try would be to do:

```
fit = glmer(
  formula = PPV_accuracy ~ brochure_between * age_within + 
             medicalcondition_within + (1|ID)
  , family = 'binomial'
  , data = DF_analysis)
```

But this does not include the medical condition or the item order as random factors.